# Can truth tables be different for equal expressions?

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

I have a equation (A'B + B'C)C'. If I simplify this down to A'B C' the truth tables are not the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For some reason the post changed my question..

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Edited the post and now question registered normally (:

Comment: Shaun - I'm not doing that particular area at the moment. I'm in college. Doing an electrical engineering course that requires me to use truth tables and logic gates.

Comment: It would be helpful to share your truth tables.

Comment: It's not an area; it's format instructions!

Comment: @peterwhy I managed to do the truth tables incorrectly the first time. I redid them and now they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

No; if 2 expressions are equal, their truth tables also yield the same result. Your simplification is correct so there must have been at least one error in your truth tables.

Comment: The site doesn't like me using certain characters... Does (A'B+B'C)C' = A'BC'

Comment: Also CC just simplifies to C?

Comment: Edited my post and now it seems to register it normally.

Comment: Yes CC does simplify to C, but now you've edited your post, the new expression simplifies to  A'BC' + B'CC'

Comment: C & C' should always equal 0. Thus eliminating that entire term, I believe. Simplifying the equation to A'BC'. The problem is the truth table for A'BC' and the original equation are different ):

Comment: Yes what you say seems true and if so, the truth tables must be the same, so there must be an error in your truth table.

Comment: Okay, I just did the truth tables wrong...... After redoing them it seems to be correct. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: By the way, in the context of your question, you should say 'equal expressions', rather than 'equal equations'. The 2 sides of any equation are equal by definition, unless the equation is erroneous, in which case it's technically not an equation anymore.

Comment: I will take note of that.